# Refactoring plugins like Resharper or Visual Assist X for VS2012 for D (DMD)?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, ide, refactoring, d

Are there any refactoring plugins like Resharper or Visual Assist X for VS2012 for D (DMD)?

Feel free to mention any IDEs that have the functionality built-in.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick answer: no.

Sadly, there's not much tools for D yet. You should refer to [this page](http://wiki.dlang.org/IDEs) for the list of IDE and some of their features. It's updated often. As of now, the only VS tool is [VisualD](http://www.dsource.org/projects/visuald).

Answer (score 1):

Mono-D, plugin for MonoDevelop, and DDT, plugin for Eclipse, have very, very basic refactoring capabilities. At the moment of writing this answer there is no tool that is even remotely close to refactoring capabilities of NetBeans/IdeaJ/Eclipse when it comes to Java.